# Flying Sauces-> Stream closed error occured repeteadly

Tags: image, stream, ioexception, recurrence, flying-saucer

I use Flying Saucer to generate a screenshot of websites (Any website, so I don't have any control on it).
So, for some of them, because of their construction, errors occure. 
The problem is, for some of them, I have this "Stream Closed" error, which occures repeatedly. Since the problem is inside the program of Flying Saucer, I can't access it (but I can see the error), and I can't stop it.
I tried to put the problematic action in a thread, that I could close in case of error, but there is no way that my code detect the error.
Here is my code :

```
Tidy tidy=new Tidy();
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        tidy.setForceOutput(true);
        tidy.setShowWarnings(false);
        tidy.setQuiet(true);
        String[] dirPaths=new String[]
        {
            PropertiesManager.getProperty(DYNAMIC_IMAGES_ROOT),
            PropertiesManager.getProperty(DYNAMIC_IMAGES_TEMPLATE),
            PropertiesManager.getProperty(DYNAMIC_IMAGES_TEMP)
        };
        String path=PathConstructor.getPath(dirPaths);
        File temporaryXhtmlFile=new File(path,GenericFunctions.getUrlRoot(url)+".html");
        if(!temporaryXhtmlFile.getParentFile().exists())
            temporaryXhtmlFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();    
        temporaryXhtmlFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fous=new FileOutputStream(temporaryXhtmlFile);
        InputStream inputStream=new URL(url).openStream();
        tidy.parse(inputStream, fous);
        fous.close();
        String finalUrl=temporaryXhtmlFile.toURI().toURL().toString();
        final Java2DRenderer renderer = new Java2DRenderer(finalUrl,width,height);
        renderer.setBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        final CountDownLatch cdl=new CountDownLatch(1);
        final BufferedImage[] bufferedImageArray=new BufferedImage[1];
        Thread getImageThread=new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bufferedImageArray[0]=renderer.getImage();
                cdl.countDown();
            }
        };
        getImageThread.start();
        try {
            cdl.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            getImageThread.interrupt();
        }
        File finalFile=new File(path,fileName);
        saveImage(finalFile, bufferedImageArray[0]);
        temporaryXhtmlFile.delete();
```

and my error (who is repeated about each 30 seconds)

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.getInIfOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.zzRefill(Lexer.java:1634)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.Lexer.yylex(Lexer.java:1865)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.next(CSSParser.java:1798)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.la(CSSParser.java:1810)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.stylesheet(CSSParser.java:159)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.css.parser.CSSParser.parseStylesheet(CSSParser.java:89)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:78)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:95)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.getStylesheet(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:174)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.readAndParseAll(StyleReference.java:123)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StyleReference.setDocumentContext(StyleReference.java:107)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.Java2DRenderer.setDocument(Java2DRenderer.java:317)
at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.Java2DRenderer.getImage(Java2DRenderer.java:265)
```

I take any suggestion.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The error you described has been causing lots of trouble to me also some other day. The solution to your problem is to **specify the correct css stylesheet address** so that xhtmlrenderer can access your css file.

For example if you have some style sheet or image as 
`/styles/samplestyle.css` in your html file, you have to convert it as`filepath/styles/samplestyles.css` 
and **same apply for images also**. I believe this will solve your problem.

The directory path should be in `C:/filepath/` or any other disk in which your style sheets are saved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and fixed it by adding `file` prefix when including css file in the freemarker template. So this does not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/opt/3six5/template/style.css"/>
```

And this works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///opt/3six5/template/style.css"/>
```